# WCF Service start error - Service has zero application endpoints

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, wcf

I'm trying to start a windows service and I'm getting the following error:

> Service cannot be started. System.InvalidOperationException: Service
>   'LazyPCAndroiderSvc.LazyPCController' has zero application
>   (non-infrastructure) endpoints. This might be because no configuration
>   file was found for your application, or because no service element
>   matching the service name could be found in the configuration file, or
>   because no endpoints were defined in the service element.

?

I've already tested the service using WCF Tester and it posed no problem. Only when I try to run this as a windows service, it causes the above error.

Here is my app.config from the wcf service:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <!-- This section is optional with the new configuration model
           introduced in .NET Framework 4. -->
      <service name="LazyPCAndroiderSvc.LazyPCController"
               behaviorConfiguration="LazyPCControllerBehavior">
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8750/LazyPCAndroiderSvc/LazyPCController/"/>
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>

        <endpoint address=""
                  binding="wsHttpBinding"
                  contract="LazyPCAndroiderSvc.ILazyPCController" />

        <endpoint address="mex"
                  binding="mexHttpBinding"
                  contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="LazyPCControllerBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

I've verified that the names match perfectly (Including the namespace).

Here is my WindowsService code:

```
namespace LazyPCAndroiderWinSvc
{
    public partial class Service : ServiceBase
    {
        ServiceHost sHost;
        public Service()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            sHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(LazyPCAndroiderSvc.LazyPCController));
            sHost.Open();
        }

        protected override void OnStop()
        {
            sHost.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

This seems like a trivial problem but I cannot locate the cause.

Comment: What is the path to the exe that service pointing to? Is <application name>.exe.config present at that location?

Comment: @YK1 WCF Service is part of VS Solution that's loaded as a reference, so it's a DLL. All LazyPCAndroiderSvc.dll, LazyPCAndroiderSvc.dll. config,App.config Are present in the WCF Service folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Service may not read automatically from `LazyPCAndroiderSvc.dll.config` - put those configurations in your main exe's App.config

Comment: Sorry, I'm a bit confused, are you saying that I need to put my LazyPCAndroiderSvc.dll.config path into my Windows Service exe configuration? (LazyPCAndroiderWinSvc)? How do I do this? I couldn't find an app.config for the windows service, it only exists for my WCF Service.

Comment: you add an app.config to your EXE project. Copy the system.ServiceModel contents of dll.config to exe.config.

Comment: Wow, that fixed the problem! This is pretty bewildering but it works

Comment: I did something else even more stupid ... my app.config file was named app.cfg. Caused the same error and it took me a day of toil to find it.